# Geospatial functions in Amazon Kinesis Analytics with SQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Is possible to process geospatials datas with SQL in Kinesis Data Analytics like Microsoft do it using [stream analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-geospatial-functions)?

If is not possible using SQL, I suppose I have to use the new feature of Apache Flink in Kinesis Data Analytics

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kinesis Data Analytics to store the data using firehose into an AWS datastore, and then query the data using AWS [Athena geospatial queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-geospatial-data.html).

Comment: But I suppose doing this is not the same as streaming analytics. I mean, I couldn't detect in real time if exits any alarm in the incoming data